# Round Robin Algorithm, processes dont finish executing

Tags: java, algorithm, cpu, scheduler, round-robin

I'm writing a simple cpu scheduler simulator, currently im at Round Robin algorithm. At this little piece of code, my way of implementing it is this:
take the total sum of the burst time from user input for keeping track when 
this block should finish. as long as the sum is greater then or equal to 0, keep executing.

now, the problem is that the sum becomes negative and the block stops executing before the processes' burst time become all 0. is there any way i can fix this?

for example, suppose in our case that our input is {9, 12, 1, 1, 4, 4},
the output for phase 1 after executing all processes with quantum 4 is:
(where first column is the original array and the second one the decremented by quantum's value)

```
sum: 31

phase nr: 1
9 7     not zero
12 10   not zero
1 0     check
1 0     check
4 2     not zero
4 2     not zero

phase nr: 2
7 5     not zero
10 8    not zero
0 0     check
0 0     check
2 0     check
2 0     check
```

at this stage sum becomes negative and stops printing other processes

this is the code ive been working so far. i dont know if this explanation is clear enough, i tried to be as clear and specific as i could.

note: all jobs has an arrival time of 0

```
int[] a = {9, 12, 1, 1, 4, 4};
        int sum = 0;

        //total sum of the a[]
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {
            sum += a[i];            
        }
        System.out.printf("\nsum: %d\n\n", sum);

        int counter = 1;
        while(sum >= 0)
        {
            System.out.printf("\nphase nr: %d\n", counter);

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
            {
                //prints the original array
                System.out.printf("%d ",a[i]);
                int value = a[i]; //takes a value from a[] at index i
                value -= 2;      //decrement the value by quantum 2
                a[i] = value;   //put the value at the same index
                if (a[i] < 0)  //it checks if any element is less than 0, if yes replace it with 0
                {
                    a[i] = 0;
                }

                /**
                 *prints the array after subtracting 2 from each element 
                 *in the original array and checks if there is any value
                 *equal to 0, if yes print "check" else "not zero"
                 */
                System.out.printf("%d \t%s",a[i], a[i]==0?"check":"not zero");
                System.out.println();
            }

            /**
             * decrements the sum based on the quantum 
             * multiplied by processes 
             * sum = sum -(quantum * numberOfProcesses)
             */
            sum = sum - (4 * 6);

            counter++;
        }
```

Comment: Your quantum here sum = sum - (4 * 6); should be 2 instead of 4 right?

Comment: Why do you subtract a constant number from sum? If process takes 1 quantum of time you should subtract 1 from sum, right? So the processes won't end even if you fix problem that @javadev mentioned.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: @qwerqwerqwersdfadzxvzxcvzxcv *why*?  Your question is good, you don't need to destroy your posts just "for no reason".  (Others could also learn from these posts, which is why you don't get to just "destroy" your own content for no reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in calculating your sum.

**sum = sum - (4 * 6);**

You subtract 24 in every iteration even if processes finish earlier(like in 1 quantum of time) or are already finished.

What you should subtract from sum in every iteration is the total time spent on actual processing. So if process is done (a[i] == 0) you don't proceed, and if the a[i] < 4 you subtract that value. Only when a[i] >=4 you should subtract 4 quanta.

If you want to spend 4 quanta of time for every process regardless of its real needs and if it's done or not then you calculate your sum wrong and it's not really Round Robin.

while(sum >= 0)
        {
            System.out.printf("\nphase nr: %d\n", counter);

```
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {
            //prints the original array
            System.out.printf("%d ",a[i]);
            int value = a[i]; //takes a value from a[] at index i
            if(a[i] == 0) { continue;} // skip process if it's done
            else if(a[i]<=4) { sum -=a[i]; a[i]=0;} // if process is less than one quantum then it's done and sum is decreased by time needed
            else { sum -=4; a[i] -=4} // otherwise process needs more than one quantum so it uses up all 4

            /**
             *prints the array after subtracting 2 from each element 
             *in the original array and checks if there is any value
             *equal to 0, if yes print "check" else "not zero"
             */
            System.out.printf("%d \t%s",a[i], a[i]==0?"check":"not zero");
            System.out.println();
        }
        // this part was completely unnecessary so it was removed to for loop above

        counter++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure too fully understand your algorithm, but the computation of the sum is not correct. You should define some function that will sum the actual values in the array a[] instead of having some wrong constant computation (you use 4 for quantum instead of 2) and ignore the fact that some a's are not decremented once they are set to 0.

You can define something like :

```
public static int totalBurstTime(int[] bursts) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int b : bursts) {
        total += b;
    }
    return total;
}
```

and call it to initialise the sum before the while loop, and then at the end of each loop.

Also, you should use some constants instead of magic numbers, eg

```
static final int QUANTUM = 2;
```

and use it everywhere you need...